# How to escape double quotes in bcp sql query in stored procedure sql server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, bcp

The following is my stored procedure code:

```
Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[ConvertToFile]

    @TempFileName varchar(8000)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;

    DECLARE @bcpFileCmd varchar(8000)


SET @bcpFileCmd= 'bcp "SELECT id,full_Name,message from NotesTable " queryout '+@TempFileName+' -t, -c -T'

    EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @bcpFileCmd

END
```

BCP dumps all the data from NotesTable in file. But I need to enclose the message results with double quotes. The datatype for message field is text. I'm not able to append it in select query in BCP.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to concatenate double quotes to the beginning and end of your message results, and escape both the single quotes and double quotes:

```
SET @bcpFileCmd= 'bcp "SELECT id, full_Name, ''""'' + message + ''""'' from NotesTable " queryout '+@TempFileName+' -t, -c -T'
```

If you need to retain the column name, you should also alias it like so (might not be necessary if you're just outputting to a file):

```
SET @bcpFileCmd= 'bcp "SELECT id, full_Name, ''""'' + message + ''""'' ''message'' from NotesTable " queryout '+@TempFileName+' -t, -c -T'
```